# Consider any $\delta \gt c \gt 0$. Prove that there is a $k \in \mathbb N$ and $z \in \mathbb N$ such that $z\cdot \frac{1}{k} \in [c, \delta)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification

I needed this lemma for an exercise and wondered if there were more traditional ways of proving it.

> Consider any $\delta \gt c \gt 0$. Prove that there is a $k \in \mathbb N$ and $z \in \mathbb N$ such that $z\cdot \frac{1}{k} \in [c, \delta)$.

---

By the *Archimedean Property*, there is a $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{k} \lt |c - \delta|$.

There are three possibilities:

Case 1) $\frac{1}{k} = c$

Case 2) $\frac{1}{k} \gt c$

Case 3) $\frac{1}{k} \lt c$

In **Case 1**, simply let $z=1$.

In **Case 2**, recalling that $\frac{1}{k} \lt |c-\delta|=\delta -c$, we have that $\frac{1}{k}+c \lt \delta$. Noting that $c \gt 0$, we then have: $\frac{1}{k} \lt \frac{1}{k}+c \lt \delta$, which implies that $\frac{1}{k} \lt \delta$. Combining this with $\frac{1}{k}\gt c$, it is clear that $\frac{1}{k} \in (c,\delta)$. We can therefore let $z=1$.

In **Case 3**, we first note that, because $\mathbb N$ is an unbounded set, there is a $z'$ such that $z' \geq ck$. Rearranging, we have that $\frac{1}{k}\cdot z' \geq c$. If $\frac{1}{k}\cdot z'=c$, we are done. So let $\frac{1}{k}\cdot z' \gt c$.

Now, consider the set $S=\left\{z \in \mathbb N: \frac{1}{k}\cdot z \gt c\right\}$. By assumption, we know $\frac{1}{k}\cdot z' \gt c$, so clearly $z' \in S$, which means $S \neq \emptyset$. Therefore, by the *Well-Ordering Principle*, there is a minimum element $z^* \in S$. Importantly, because $\frac{1}{k} \lt c$, we must have $z^* \geq 2$. Consider the natural number $(z^*-1)$, which we know exists because $(z^*-1) \geq 1$. Clearly, $(z^*-1) \notin S$  because $z^*-1 \lt z^*$ and $z^*$ is the minimum element of $S$. This means that $\frac{1}{k}\cdot (z^*-1) \leq c$. If equal, we are done. So suppose $\frac{1}{k}\cdot (z^*-1) \lt c \quad (*)$.

Recalling that $\frac{1}{k} \lt \delta -c$, we have that $c+\frac{1}{k} \lt \delta$. In combination with $(*)$, we then have:

$$\frac{1}{k}\cdot(z^*-1)+\frac{1}{k} \lt c+\frac{1}{k} \lt \delta$$

Noting that $\frac{1}{k}(z^*-1)+ \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{k} \cdot z^*$, we must have $\frac{1}{k}\cdot z^*\lt \delta$. Because $z^* \in S$, we conclude with $c \lt \frac{1}{k} \cdot z^* \lt \delta \iff \frac{1}{k} \cdot z^* \in (c,\delta)$.

Comment: Do you mean, Consider any $c, \delta\ $ with $ \delta > c > 0\ ?$

Comment: @AdamRubinson whoops. Yup. Good catch - I'll make the necessary changes. Cheers~

Comment: In any non-zero interval there are rational numbers, since rationals are dense among reals.  Numerator and denominator of any rational will do.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes, but this is exactly what this question sets out to prove, isn't it? So unless you had some other way to prove that the rationals are dense in the reals then this seems circular

Comment: @StephenDonovan The question didn't look to me as asking to prove rationals are dense in the reals, although that may have been the intent.

Answer (score 1):

I like your proof, but I think this is a shorter proof in the same vein:

$z \cdot \frac{1}{k} \in [c, \delta)$ is equivalent to $c \leq \frac{z}{k} < \delta,$ or in turn $ck \leq z < \delta k.$ As you note, by the Archimedean property we have that there exists some natural $k$ such that $\frac{1}{k} < \delta - c,$ so $1 < \delta k - ck$ and $ck + 1 < \delta k.$

Now let $z$ be the smallest integer greater than or equal to $ck.$ We must have that $z < ck + 1,$ because otherwise if $z \geq ck + 1$ then $z - 1 \geq ck,$ and because $z - 1$ is an integer if $z$ is then $z$ is not the smallest integer greater than $ck,$ causing a contradiction. So, $ck \leq z < ck + 1 < \delta k.$

The key elements here are that we can always make $[ck, \delta k)$ have a length of at least $1,$ and that in any interval of length at least $1$ there must be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ c,\ \delta\ $ be such that $ \delta > c > 0.$

By the *Archimedean Property*, there is a $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $\ 0<\frac{1}{k} \lt \delta-c$.

For any $\ x>0,\ $ there is always a *maximum* non-negative integer $\ m\ $ such that $\ m<x.\quad (*) $

Since $\ ck>0,\ $ there exists a maximum non-negative integer $\ m\ $ such that $\ m < ck,\implies\frac{m}{k} < c.\ $ Then $\ \frac{m+1}{k}\geq c\ $ and  $\ \frac{m}{k} + \frac{1}{k} < c + \frac{1}{k} < c + \delta - c = \delta,\ $ i.e., $\ c\leq\frac{m+1}{k}<\delta,\ $ and the result is proven with $\ z= m+1.$

$\ (*)\ $ is true because $\ 0<x,\ $ and so if $\ (*)\ $ weren't true, then $\ x\ $ is greater than every non-negative integer, and no real number has this property.